# Why were evil numbers named "evil"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, definition, philosophy

According to the entry for Sloane sequence A001969:

> Evil numbers: nonnegative integers with an even number of 1's in their binary expansion.

And deeper inside that entry it states that

> The terms "evil numbers" and "odious numbers" were coined by Richard K. Guy, c. 1976 (Haque and Shallit, 2016) and appeared in the book by Berlekamp et al. (Vol. 1, 1st ed., 1982). - Amiram Eldar, Jun 08 2021

What did Richard K. Guy see in these numbers that caused him to think that "evil" is the best description for them?

Comment: [guess only] [ev]en/[ev]il and [od]d/[od]ious. In other words it may have simply been a linguistic joke...

Comment: @coffeemath probably. He seems to be [funny](https://www.ams.org/notices/202204/rnoti-p574.pdf).

Comment: Strange humor. There's nothing funny about evil *at all*. It costed Adam and Eve paradise.

Comment: Numerologies (such as the "number of the beast $666$") do usually not matter , but in some cases have absurd consequences. That there are seriously airlines omitting the seat $13$ (because some people believe it is a number of bad luck) is not funny anymore. As the religions show , people have alway been attracted to pure mystic with no link to reality.

Comment: It is a bit amusing that a question about the root of evil (numbers) digresses into a discussion of numerology (which was the root of all evil (number theory) in some prior math platforms).

Comment: @coffeemath Ok so a lame pun joke. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @HolyKnowing Note that my comment was only a *guess* as to the choice of terms by Guy. I have no knowledge on the topic from any written source.